# Attribute column/meta data requirement for document upload to Teams/SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have a folder that I am trying to use to trigger an approval flow.  But first, I need the user to specify a dollar amount, which will (hopefully) send the flow down one of three paths.  I have added a column called "Amount" as an attribute or metadata field in the SharePoint folder.   I have set it to choice with radio buttons.  The options are: "up to 10k," "10k to 500k," and "over 500k."  I set "require that this column contains information" to yes.  Is there a way to force the user, via pop up or something to select a value?  As it stands, there are no restrictions on uploading a document.  It just shows the field as yellow in SharePoint and says "Required info."  But I want it to force the user to make the selection at time of upload.  Preferably via Teams and some kind of pop up box with the question.

Maybe I'm reaching for the stars, but figured I'd ask.

I created the column and set the requirement to yes.  My expectation was that the user is prompted at time of upload to select one of the three values with a radio button selection.  What actually resulted is that the document uploads.  If you go to SharePoint, it shows the "error" to let you know there is Required info missing.  But other than that there is nothing prompting a user to make the selection.  They will likely be uploading via Teams, not the actual SharePoint.  [This is what you see if you select the item in SharePoint.  It says you can't leave it blank but does nothing to prevent it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFtyG.jpg)

Comment: Have you added the column to the default view in the Files tab? At least that will make it more visible to the user that it needs to be set, right in the files list without opening the 'info' panel like in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, this is not possible. User will be able to upload a file anyway, no matter if you have some fields set to "required". Before (in "classic" experience) it was not like this, and there was a prompt, but it was causing more troubles than it was brining benefits, and they removed it in the modern experience.

Check out this as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/upload-file-using-new-experience

If you want your own user experience, you can build it yourself (think "custom Teams app" for example) instead of using the stock SharePoint UI.